# Cepstrum and Formant Tracking Using Apple Accelerate Framework

Tags: ios, signal-processing, fft, accelerate-framework

I've been using this web page as a guideline for formant tracking of speech...

http://iitg.vlab.co.in/?sub=59&brch=164&sim=615&cnt=1

It all seems to be going pretty well, except for the last step, which is the converting of the cepstrum into a smoothed representation for simple peak picking for the formant tracking.  The spectrograph looks good, and the cepstrograph (can I say that? :P) also looks good (from what I can tell), but the final stage the results (smoothed formant representation) are not what I expected.

I uploaded a sample of each stage as visual images to...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMUTU.jpg

This sample is for the speech of the sound 'i' as in 'beed'.  According to this site...

http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~robh/howto.html#formants

the first formant should come in around 500hz, and the second and third around 2200hz and 2800 hz respectively.  The spetrograph shows something very similar, but on the last stage I am gettings results similar to...

F1 - 891
F2 - 1550
F3 - 2329

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  I've been going round in circles on this for some time.  My code looks as follows...

```
// set up fft parameters
UInt32 log2n = 9;
UInt32 n = 512;
UInt32 window = n;
UInt32 halfN = n/2;
UInt32 stride = 1;
FFTSetup setupReal = [appDelegate getFftSetup];
int stepSize = (hpBuffer.sampleCount-window) / quantizeCount;

// calculate volume from raw samples, because it seems more reliable that fft
UInt32 volumeWindow = 128;
volumeBuffer = malloc(sizeof(float)*quantizeCount);
int windowPos = 0;
for (int i=0; i < quantizeCount; i++) {
    windowPos += stepSize;
    float total = 0.0f;
    float max = 0.0f;
    for (int p=windowPos; p < windowPos+volumeWindow; p++) {
        total += sampleBuffer.buffer[p];
        if (sampleBuffer.buffer[p] > max)
            max = sampleBuffer.buffer[p];
    }
    volumeBuffer[i] = max;
}

// normalize volumebuffer
[FloatAudioBuffer normalizePositiveBuffer:volumeBuffer ofSize:quantizeCount];

// allocate memory for complex array
COMPLEX_SPLIT complexArray;
complexArray.realp = (float*)malloc(4096*sizeof(float));
complexArray.imagp = (float*)malloc(4096*sizeof(float));

// allocate some space for temporary hamming buffer
float *hamBuffer = malloc(n*sizeof(float));

// create spectrum and feature buffer
spectrumBuffer = malloc(sizeof(float)*halfN*quantizeCount);
formantBuffer = malloc(sizeof(float)*4096*quantizeCount);
cepstrumBuffer = malloc(sizeof(float)*halfN*quantizeCount);
lowCepstrumBuffer = malloc(sizeof(float)*featureCount*quantizeCount);
featureBuffer = malloc(sizeof(float)*featureCount*quantizeCount);

// create data point for each quantize segment
float TWOPI = 2.0f * M_PI;
for (int s=0; s < quantizeCount; s++) {
    // copy buffer data into a seperate array and apply hamming window
    int offset = (int)(s * stepSize);
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        hamBuffer[i] = hpBuffer.buffer[offset+i] * ((1.0f-0.46f) - 0.46f*cos(TWOPI*i/((float)n-1.0f)));

    // configure float array into acceptable input array format (interleaved)
    vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)hamBuffer, 2, &complexArray, 1, halfN);

    // run FFT
    vDSP_fft_zrip(setupReal, &complexArray, stride, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

    // Absolute square (equivalent to mag^2)
    complexArray.imagp[0] = 0.0f;
    vDSP_zvmags(&complexArray, 1, complexArray.realp, 1, halfN);
    bzero(complexArray.imagp, (halfN) * sizeof(float));

    // scale
    float scale = 1.0f / (2.0f*(float)n);
    vDSP_vsmul(complexArray.realp, 1, &scale, complexArray.realp, 1, halfN);

    // get log of absolute values for passing to inverse FFT for cepstrum
    for (int i=0; i < halfN; i++)
        complexArray.realp[i] = logf(sqrtf(complexArray.realp[i]));

    // save this into spectrum buffer
    memcpy(&spectrumBuffer[s*halfN], complexArray.realp, halfN*sizeof(float));


    // convert spectrum to interleaved ready for inverse fft
    vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)&spectrumBuffer[s*halfN], 2, &complexArray, 1, halfN/2);

    // create cepstrum
    vDSP_fft_zrip(setupReal, &complexArray, stride, log2n-1, FFT_INVERSE);

    //convert interleaved to real and straight into cepstrum buffer
    vDSP_ztoc(&complexArray, 1, (COMPLEX*)&cepstrumBuffer[s*halfN], 2, halfN/2);

    // copy first part of cepstrum into low cepstrum buffer
    memcpy(&lowCepstrumBuffer[s*featureCount], &cepstrumBuffer[s*halfN], featureCount*sizeof(float));

    // make 8000 point array based on the first 15 values
    float *tempArray = malloc(8192*sizeof(float));
    for (int i=0; i < 8192; i++) {
        if (i < 15)
            tempArray[i] = cepstrumBuffer[s*halfN+i];
        else
            tempArray[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)tempArray, 2, &complexArray, 1, 4096);
    float newLog2n = log2f(8192.0f);
    complexArray.imagp[0] = 0.0f;
    vDSP_fft_zrip(setupReal, &complexArray, stride, newLog2n, FFT_FORWARD);
    vDSP_zvmags(&complexArray, 1, complexArray.realp, 1, 4096);
    bzero(complexArray.imagp, (4096) * sizeof(float));

    // scale
    scale = 1.0f / (2.0f*(float)8192);
    vDSP_vsmul(complexArray.realp, 1, &scale, complexArray.realp, 1, 4096);

    // get magnitude
    for (int i=0; i < 4096; i++)
        complexArray.realp[i] = sqrtf(complexArray.realp[i]);

    // write to formant buffer
    memcpy(&formantBuffer[s*4096], complexArray.realp, 4096*sizeof(float));

    // complex array now contains formant spectrum
    // it's large, so get features here!
    // try simple peak picking algorithm for first 3 formants
    int formantIndex = 0;
    float *peaks = malloc(6*sizeof(float));
    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++)
        peaks[i] = 0.0f;
    for (int i=1; i < 4096-1 && formantIndex < 6; i++) {
        if (complexArray.realp[i-1] < complexArray.realp[i] &&
            complexArray.realp[i+1] < complexArray.realp[i])
            peaks[formantIndex++] = i;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered normalizing your data?